# How to get Google search results estimate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

is there a way to get Google's search results estimate in Ruby? I'm looking to return the values where Google says there are "About 32,300,000 results" after searching for a particular term. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, there are ways. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried scraping and using Google Custom Search Engine. Google Custom Search Engine does not return the same values as what I see on the browser

What do you recommend? I got a feeling that scraping might not be the most elegant solution

Comment: "I got a feeling that scraping might not be the most elegant solution". Correct. [Google has a Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) they want you to take advantage of. Using it will avoid violating their terms of service, and will present you information directly.

Comment: It looks like scraping is your only solution w/ Google. I have seen other APIs (namely Bing) have APIs that return this data if you're open to other data sources

Comment: @theTinMan I could be misunderstanding Google's CSE product but it seems to be for specific sites whereas the OP presumably wants to know for all sites Google has indexed

Comment: Google deprecated their old search API. While it does work still, it's [very limited](https://developers.google.com/web-search/terms).

Comment: @Skram Yes I am using Bing as an alternative, but still prefer to get Google search result estimate data. I did try with Google CSE but the search results estimate differs from what I get on the browser.

Comment: @theTinMan do you mean that the old search API will return the total search results estimate like what I see on the browser? Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the example code in my answer?

Comment: @theTinMan Yup I saw your code. I cross-checked some search queries but the search results estimate on the browser do not seem to match the one returned from the API. Nevertheless it still works to some extent. Thank you very much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a feeling that scraping might not be the most elegant solution.

Correct. [Google has a Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) they want you to take advantage of. Using it will avoid violating their terms of service, and will present you information directly.

In particular, their REST API can return JSON based on simple queries.

They used to have a more "normal" interface that acted like their web-based search pages do, but that was deprecated in favor of the Custom Search API. I suspect that was because the first was the shotgun approach and would consume a huge amount of CPU time, where the newer API targets specific sites/searches.

https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

Here's a little snippet showing how that'd work, based on [their old Perl sample](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#fonje_snippets):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'
require 'socket'
require 'open-uri'

IP = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)

# The request also includes the userip parameter which provides the end
# user's IP address. Doing so will help distinguish this legitimate
# server-side traffic from traffic which doesn't come from an end-user.
URL = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=lectures&userip=#{ IP }"

body = open(URL).read

# process the json string
response = JSON[body]

response['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'] 
# => "13800000"
```

Be aware that Google is limiting that interface, and its lifespan is unknown, so using it could be a waste of your time. Use their Custom Search Engine instead.